# Flash previewer / explorer / browser tool for .FLA files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

We're a game development studio and we have a lot of art assets hidden inside lots of different .FLA files.

I want to visually explore the assets inside my .FLA files without having to dig through the library tree in Flash CS6 for each .FLA, because it's slow and bulky and some of the libraries are disorganized. I'd like all the assets to be laid out in a visually flat display (like a folder with thumbnails of images).

I have searched extensively for a tool like this many times in the past, and haven't found anything that does this, perhaps because it doesn't exist, or perhaps because I'm not searching for the right terminology.

Are there any tools that do this?

Comment: Haven't heard of any, but you might look for jsfl - that's where you should start from :) It can browse .fla files and get/modify their contents.